# How to represent all values of a given type in Scala

Tags: scala

I try to design a trait `Condition` for filtering purpose, and I need a way to represent all values of a given type.

```
  sealed trait Condition[+A]
  case object All extends Condition[Nothing]
  case class In[A](values : Set[A]) extends Condition[A]

  def match_?[T](conditions: Set[Condition[T]])(v: Any)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) =
    tag.runtimeClass.isAssignableFrom(v.getClass)

  val allString : Set[Condition[String]] = Set(All)
  val allTuples : Set[Condition[Tuple2[_, _]]] = Set(All)

  println(match_?(allString)("toto")) // should return true
  println(match_?(allString)(2)) // should return false

  println(match_?(allTuples)("toto")) // should return false
  println(match_?(allTuples)((1,2))) // should return true
```

I'm not used to reflection in Scala. Any idea to improve ? Is there a better way to achieve that ?

[update] should I use `ClassTag` or `TypeTag` in this case.

Comment: Given your type erasure your current approach can only work with reflection (as you're doing). However, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you can clarify the question. In its current state, I don't understand why you're not simply passing an instance of `Class[T]` as first argument to your curried function `match_?`, i.e., `def match_?[T](c: Class[T])(v: Any) = c.isAssignableFrom(v.getClass)`, called as `match_?(classOf[String])("toto")`

Comment: In fact, the program is divided in two parts. First, I retrieve `condition` from an external source. And then, I match some values against these conditions.